# Is it possible to use lightning:recordEditForm dynamically on different object types with variable objectApiName?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-inputfield, lightning-recordeditform

I need to create an edit component for an SObject from which I do not know the objectApiName at design time. I only know the Id of the SObject. objectApiName could be any valid SObject-name.

Now I want to use `lightning:inputField`

This needs to be wrapped by `lightning:recordEditForm`

In case I hardcode it to "Order", provide a vaild Order Id and let the controller load the order and assign it to the Parent-attribute, this works flawlessly:

```
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" default="" />
<aura:attribute name="Parent" type="SObject" default="{}" />
<aura:attribute name="ParentType" type="String" default="" />
<b>{!v.ParentType}({!v.recordId})</b>
<br/>
<lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!v.recordId}"  objectApiName="Order">
    <lightning:messages />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" />
    <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="update" label="Update" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

It looks like below and even the Update-button works as expected and saves the record:

[image]

But what I really want is

```
<lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!v.recordId}"  objectApiName="{!v.ParentType}">
```

Note the **{!v.ParentType}** instead of the hardcoded "Order"

As an great unfortunate, this only collapses to that error-popup

[image]

In the screenshot you see, that the ParentType is correctly bound to v.ParentType (right above the button) which a I also verify in the console

**Suspicion**

I set the ParentType-attribute as a result of APEX call (asynchronously). This seems to be too late for the lightning:recordEditForm. It tries to render with objectApiName at a time where it is still blank, hence it crashes during initialization...

**Question**

Is there a clean way to avoid this and get something to fly with an dynamic objectApiName?

**Trying to use $A.createComponents()**

As @sfdcfox suggested I jump on the $A.createComponents() which turned indeed out to be tricky, exactly as sfdcfox has predicted. Im following this [documentation here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm).

Added a button to the markup

Added a handler to the js-controller:

```
makeEdit : function(cmp, evt, hlp) { 
    console.log('ParentId :: ', cmp.get("v.ParentId") ); 
    console.log('ParentType :: ', cmp.get("v.ParentType") ); 
    $A.createComponents([
            ["lightning:recordEditForm",{
                "recordId"          : cmp.get("v.ParentId"),
                "objectApiName"     : cmp.get("v.ParentType"),
            }],
            ["lightning:inputField",{
                "fieldName" : "Name"
            }]
        ]
        ,function(components, status, errorMessage){
            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                var wrapper         = components[0];
                var inner           = components[1];
                wrapper.set("v.body", inner);
            }
            else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                // Show offline error
            }
            else if (status === "ERROR") {
                console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                // Show error message
            }
        }
    );
},
```

Now I can press the button - but nothing - I repeat: **n o t h i n g** - gets rendered at all. What is my fault here? Note that the console.log get output and the attribute are holding good values.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this is one of those times you'd have to do some $A.createComponents logic, which might also get a bit tricky.

Comment: just too sad that presumably simple things sometimes turns out complicated in lightning... an interesting observation though: when I add a button with a handler which sets a different recordId on the lightning:recordEditForm, it ignores it (why?) but if I update it to null, it falls into create-new-object-mode - but it's a one-shot: once in new-mode, forever in new-mode and subsequential updates of recordId get ignored again. Looks like lightning:recordEditForm is not designed to get it's properties changed after it's initial rendering. But why?

Comment: My guess is for performance reasons. Like what happens when you try to change a lightning:input type dynamically. It's simply not supported. I don't know if they'll ever get it fixed, but for now, I think you might need to do dynamic form creation.

Comment: @sfdcfox trying to $A.create the recordEditForm dynamically, but as you assumed: not working easily. Will update my question with the code soon...

Comment: @sfdcfox as you suggested and as you predicted: see my $A.create-updates above. Result is nothing, which isn't much. Obviously I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: If the object has record types, the recordTypeId attribute has to be set if there's no default record type. Try setting either the default record type on the user profile or specifying the desired record type id. More info at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_recordEditForm.htm

Comment: @LukeFreeland no record types on the object. the error is just misleading and presumably also wrong, because it works with the hardcoded api-name WITHOUT the recordTypeId. It just gets messed up changing the attributes after initial rendering.

Comment: since the original issue is resolved here with an viable workaround provided by @PranayJaislaw, I have forked the $A.create-part into this new question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/216762/how-to-use-a-createcomponents-on-lightningrecordeditform-with-nested-lightni

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I faced a similar issue, I managed to solve it using **aura:if**

aura:if doesnt create the inner components unless the condition is true. You can use it to your advantage.

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!!empty(v.ParentType)}">
<lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!v.recordId}"  objectApiName="{!v.ParentType}">
</aura:if>
```

> The inner component and its contents are only created and rendered if
>   the value of the isTrue expression evaluates to true. If the value of
>   the isTrue expression changes and evaluates to false, all the
>   components inside the  tag are destroyed. The components are
>   created again if the isTrue expression changes again and evaluates to
>   true.
>
> The general guideline is to use  because it helps your
>   components load faster initially by deferring the creation and
>   rendering of the enclosed element tree until the condition is
>   fulfilled.

Thus when your component is loaded even before calling init event, **lightning:recordEditForm** wont render as **v.ParentType** will be null.

After your init is called and you set the value of v.ParentType then automatically it will start rendering the lightning:recordEditForm. As ParentType is not null, it wont throw an ugly error.

SRC: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_conditional_markup.htm

Comment: oh ja, that rocks! thx a lot! So as a take away it seems, that we have only ONE shot on objectApiName and can not change it later. So we have to shoot late to hit.

Comment: You probably can.. but it might go ugly. Make ParentType as null first, it will destroy the inner component and then set ParentType as something new, it will help you create with a different type.

Comment: the null-trick is not working here. I have tried it, see my comments above: null makes it to enter create-new-record-mode, which once initiated, can not be left by providing a good recordId plus objectApiName later on... sad but true.